# Is double arrow operator a thing in C++?

Tags: c++

```
1   #include "Cube.h"
2   using cs225::Cube;
3 
4   int main() {
5       Cube *c1 = new Cube();
6       Cube *c2 = c1;
7       c2->setLength(10);

8       return 0;
9   }
```

This is the code I am working with, is there anything wrong with it? Does line 7 correctly assign the length of 10 to the cube object, or will it return a compiler error. Because my understanding is that the arrow operator will point c2 to c1, but c1 is still a pointer so shouldn't there needs to be ->-> in order to reach the cube object that contains the functions?

Comment: `c2` doesn't point to `c1`. It points *to the same thing as* `c1`, so `c2->setLength(10)` is fine. And no, double arrow is not a thing. If you had `Cube **c2 = &c1;`, then you'd need to do `(*c2)->setLength(10)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Cube *c2 = c1;
```

This does *not* point `c2` to `c1`, that would be done by the first line below, with the second line showing how to use it (it's *not* done with the mythical `->->` operator):

```
Cube **c2 = &c1;
(*c2)->setLength(10);
```

The original assignment takes the value of `c1` (a pointer to the `Cube` you allocated) and puts that value into `c2`. Hence both `c1` and `c2` now point at the same `Cube` object.

This is just like:

```
int answer = 42;
int otherAnswer = answer;
```

in that it sets `otherAnswer` to `42`, it doesn't make it *point* to `answer`. The fact that the original code involves pointers does not change this particular aspect.

Comment: Can you say that `c2` is a reference of `c1` then

Comment: @Lion: no. If `c2` was a reference then doing `c2 = new Cube()` would *also* change `c1` to point to the newly allocated memory. Again, this would be the same as `otherAnswer = 7` affecting `answer` as well.

Answer (score 0):

`c2` is initialized directly with the value of `c1` the pointer. So `c1 == c2`. `c2` is not a double pointer `Cube **`. You can essentially use `c2` as you would use `c1`.

Remember not to use `c2` after running `delete c1`, however.